# I'm being prompted to download my page on site open

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am trying to access my wordpress site and it was working a couple of days ago and now I am getting a prompt to download the page.

[image]

I have follow instructions on many sites to try and fix this but nothing seems to work. I have tried changing the .htaccess file via http://www.honeytechblog.com/how-to-fix-applicationx-httpd-php-trouble-in-getting-php-to-parse/

That didn't work. I try calling my hosting company to make sure PHP was enabled they said it was. I cleared my browser cache. I have open the file it prompts me to download and in it is this

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

To test to make sure PHP was actually working a made a simple small index.php that echoed THIS  IS A TEST and that worked just fine. So I guess it has something to do with Wordpress. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Apache is returning wrong content type header: `application/x-httpd-php` instead of `text/html`. Show us your htaccess?

Comment: I deleted the htaccess file because I was told that was not the right way to fix it

Answer (score 3):

Try to explicitly set PHP5 in your .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php
```

or with CGI

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
```

The same problem occurs with php4 instead of php5 enabled: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/browser-tries-to-download-php-file

It is just a guess, because I don't know the hoster or anything.
But it would at least explain why the former solution did not help.

Answer (score 1):

1. edit your **.htaccess** file to **.htaccess_old.**
2. **delete the cache** of your browser and restart the browser.
3. enter your website.